# Getting NullPointerException when tried to test two different pages

Tags: selenium, java, browser-automation, testng

I am new to automation testing and
I have been stuck on testing two different pages (HomePage and AboutPage)

**BasePage.java**

```
public class BasePage {
    protected WebDriver driver;
    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

**BaseTest.java**

```
public class BaseTest {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private final String chromeDriverPath = "src//main//resources//chromedriver.exe";
    private final String firefoxDriverPath = "src//main//resources//geckodriver.exe";

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters({"browser", "baseURL"})
    public void setUp(@Optional String browser, @Optional String baseURL) {
        driver = getBrowserType(browser);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to(baseURL);
    }

    private WebDriver getBrowserType(String browserType) {
        if (driver == null ) {
            if (browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
                 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", firefoxDriverPath);
                 return  new FirefoxDriver();
            }
            else if (browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
                return new ChromeDriver();
            }
        }
        return driver;
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null)
            driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**HomePage.java**

```
public class HomePage extends BasePage {

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    public boolean verifyHomePage() {
        return driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("foodpanda.com");
    }
}
```

**NavigationMenuComponent.java**

```
public class NavigationMenuComponent extends BasePage{

    public NavigationMenuComponent(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//ul[@class='right']//a[contains(@href, '/about')]")
    private WebElement aboutLink;

    public void test() {
         aboutLink.click();
    }
}
```

**HomePageTest.java**

```
public class HomePageTest extends BaseTest {

    private HomePage homePage;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void init() {
        homePage = PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), HomePage.class);
    }

    @Test(groups = "home-page")
    public void verifyFirstPage() {
        Assert.assertTrue(homePage.verifyHomePage());
    }
    }
```

**NavigationMenuTest.java**

```
public class NavigationMenuTest extends BaseTest{

    private NavigationMenuComponent navigationMenuComponent;

    @BeforeClass
    public void init() {
        navigationMenuComponent = PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), NavigationMenuComponent.class);
    }

    @Test(groups = "about-page")
    public void verifyAboutLink() {
       navigationMenuComponent.test();
    }
}
```

And my **testng.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <parameter name="baseURL" value="https://www.foodpanda.com/"></parameter>
    <test name="chromeTest" >
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.HomePageTest"></class>
            <class name="tests.NavigationMenuTest"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="firefoxTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.HomePageTest"></class>
            <class name="tests.NavigationMenuTest"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Here is stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.click(Unknown Source)
    at pages.HomePage.verifyAboutPage(HomePage.java:37)
    at tests.AboutPageTest.aboutPage(AboutPageTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:653)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:37)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:368)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Test ignored.JavaScript error: resource://gre/components/nsUrlClassifierListManager.js, line 287: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: Component returned failure code: 0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED) [nsIUrlClassifierDBService.getTables]
JavaScript error: resource://gre/components/nsUrlClassifierListManager.js, line 287: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: Component returned failure code: 0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED) [nsIUrlClassifierDBService.getTables]
1498838795121   Marionette  INFO    Ceased listening
```

But if I change testng.xml to test one of my classes it's work just fine

**EDIT**: The problem was solved by changing annotating `setUp()` in **BaseTest.java** from `@BeforeTest` to `@BeforeClass`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might not be finding you aboutLink element.

@FindBy(xpath = "//li[@id='menu-item-1390']/a[contains(@href, 'about')]")

I always try and avoid using numbered items in my xpath, is it possible the 1390 changes? Also your xpath assumes that the link is child not a descendant of the li element. If there is another element between them that xpath would not work. Good luck!